# React Hook Form - Yup Validation not working when I click on Submit (I am navigating to same component when clicked)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-form

I have reused Employee component which uses yup validation, validation is not working when I click on submit for second time.

```
const {
register,
handleSubmit,
formState: { errors },
control,
   } = useForm<any>({
mode: 'onChange',
resolver: yupResolver(schema),
defaultValues: reduxObject,
```

});

and I navigate to the same employee component when I click on submit based on a condition.

```
if (index) === reduxObject.data?.customers.length) {
  navigate('/CustomerPage');
} else {
  navigate('/EmployeePage'); // this component will be called multiple times based on condition
}
```

here is my actual form and when button of type submit clicked, handleSubmit submitForm gets triggered.

```
<form key={index} onSubmit={handleSubmit(SubmitForm)}>
    <Card>
      <Card.Header>Employee Details Review</Card.Header>
      <Card.Body>
        <div className="container">
          {reduxObject.isEmployeeDetails=== 'true' && (
            <Card.Text>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <Form.Label>
                    Employee Details
                  </Form.Label>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  <Controller
                    control={control}
                    rules={{
                      required: true,
                    }}
                    render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
                      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                        <Radio
                          id="isEmployee"
                          value="true"
                          checked={
                            reduxObject.data?.customers[index]?.isEmployeeDetails===
                            'true'
                          }
                          {...register('isEmployeeDetails')}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            handleChange(e.target.value, e.target.name);
                            onChange(e.target.value);
                          }}
                        >
                          Yes
                        </Radio>
                        <Radio
                          id="isEmployeeDetails"
                          value="false"
                          checked={
                            reduxObject.data?.customers[index]?.isEmployeeDetails===
                            'false'
                          }
                          {...register('isEmployeeDetails')}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            onChange(e.target.value);
                            handleChange(e.target.value, 
                              e.target.name);
                          }}
                        >
                          No
                        </Radio>
                      </div>
                    )}
                    name="isEmployeeDetails"
                  />
                  {errors.isEmployeeDetails&& (
                    <p className={styles.error} style={{ paddingLeft: 
                    '20px' }}>
                      {errors.isEmployeeDetails.message}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Card.Text>
          )}
        </div>
   </Card.Body>
  </Card>
```

Comment: It might make sense to share your full `handleSubmit` method here, not just a part of it. Or generally, more code.

Comment: @phry I have added more code. the handle submit functionality is same, based on condition check it will navigate to same component.